# Error Could not resolve "./assets/image.png" when run command "vite build" using viteJs

Tags: javascript, vite

I am using the ViteJs to config my project. I got an error when I ran the command `vite build --watch --config ./vite.config.ts`

My code is like below:

File `vite.config.js`

```js
export default defineConfig({
    plugins: [
        react(),
        nodePolyfills(),
        commonjs({
            include: /node_modules/
        }),
        babel({
            babelrc: true,
            exclude: 'node_modules/**'
        })
    ],
    assetsInclude: ['**/*.png'],
    build: {
        target: 'modules',
        commonjsOptions: {
            sourceMap: false
        },
        rollupOptions: {
            input: {
                index: './src/js/pages/Index.ts'
            },
            output: {
                format: 'cjs',
                entryFileNames: '[name].js',
                dir: './public/dist'
            }
        }
    }
});
```

File `Demo.ts`

```js
 import Image from './assets/Image.png'
```

When run command I get the error `Could not resolve "./assets/Image.png" from "Demo.ts"`

I try add option `assetsInclude: ['**/*.png'],` to config file but it not resolve.

You can help me resolve the error.
Thank you very munch!

Answer (score 0):

within `tsconfig.json` you can use

```
 "compilerOptions": {
    "types": [
      "vite/client"
    ]
 }
```